# Why I got race condition while reading file from different process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to read big text file contains 6000 lines same length.
File can be accessed through different process and I acquire mutex to prevent race conditions. But output contains partially read lines:

```
58 '444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444\n'
58 '333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333\n'
46 '444444444444444444444444442222222222222222222\n'
58 '444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444\n'
```

Code I m trying to run:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Loader:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.lock = mp.Lock()
        self.file = open(path, 'r')

    def read(self):
        with self.lock:
            try:
                line = next(self.file)
                print(len(line), repr(line))
            except StopIteration:
                return False
        return True


def worker(loader):
    while loader.read():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = Loader('./data.txt')

    workers = []
    for i in range(4):
        w = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(loader,))
        w.daemon = True
        w.start()
        workers.append(w)

    for w in workers:
        w.join()
```

Firstly, I expect that I will get error when copying `file` descriptor to another process, but program started and all process can read from this file.
But race conditions discourage me, why each process do not read whole line?

Comment: Could you please test it, using `lock` as global variable in module, not a part of Loader?

Comment: @Slam, same behavior

Comment: I think the problem is in buffering, NOT locking. Each process reads a whole block from the file and then return lines from its buffer untils it is empty and only then it reads another block from the file.The shared file offset advances in blocksize steps, not in linesize steps. Hope it helps, I do not have time right now to write more than this short comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t fail to copy a file object because you don’t **copy anything** (in the usual sense).  You’re using the (Unix) default `fork` technique and so each process inherits (a copy-on-write version of) the same open file.

So (as VPfB pointed out) each process does its own buffering, but the underlying **open file description** is shared and that contains the file offset.  If you read a character before starting the processes, you’ll see that they all report the same prefix of the file before diverging (and mixing up lines).